# Get the genre of a Song

Tags: android

How do i go about reading the genre that a song is associated to?  I can read the song, but how do i grab the genre for that song, where is it stored?

Thanks!

Comment: Look  [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785370/display-all-song-from-the-sd-card-genre-wise

Answer (score 9):

Check this code:

```
public class MusicLibraryScanner {

    private static Cursor mediaCursor;
    private static Cursor genresCursor;

    private static String[] mediaProjection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
    };
    private static String[] genresProjection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID
    };

    public static void getMusicFromStorage(Context context) {

        mediaCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                mediaProjection, null, null, null);

        int artist_column_index = mediaCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int album_column_index = mediaCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int title_column_index = mediaCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int id_column_index = mediaCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);

        if (mediaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String info = "Song " + mediaCursor.getString(title_column_index) + " ";
                info += "from album " + mediaCursor.getString(album_column_index) + " ";
                info += "by " + mediaCursor.getString(artist_column_index) + ". ";

                int musicId = Integer.parseInt(mediaCursor.getString(id_column_index));

                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.getContentUriForAudioId("external", musicId);
                genresCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                        genresProjection, null, null, null);
                int genre_column_index = genresCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);                

                if (genresCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    info += "Genres: ";
                    do {
                        info += genresCursor.getString(genre_column_index) + " ";
                    } while (genresCursor.moveToNext());
                }

                Log.e("Audio scanner", "Song info: " + info);
            } while (mediaCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the function getContentUriForAudioId ?

Comment: I have use that but it get crashed in the android 2.3.5 because there is no Method in android 2.3.6. Please help me for lower version device.

Comment: this will give you only a list of all genres, but not which genre belongs to which song

Answer (score 3):

If you are still looking for an answer -----

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,song_id);

mr.setDataSource(mContext, trackUri);

String thisGenre = mr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get it from the mp3 file it self respectively from its ID3-Tags when it was set there. There should be some java libraries out there which help you accessing theses tag from a mp3 file.

Comment: Yep, but there is no way to do so via the MediaStore?  That's what I'm looking for.